# Given the paths, how do i open it? Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am implementing a open button.

```
- (IBAction)open:(id)sender {
    NSInteger selectedRow=[tableview selectedRow];
    //if(selectedRow >=0) {
    NSString * paths=[myRecentFile objectAtIndex:selectedRow];

    NSLog(@"%@", [myRecentFile objectAtIndex:selectedRow]);

    [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openFile:(NSString *)paths withApplication:@"MainMenu"];
}
```

But I cannot open it correctly. MainMenu is nibname. paths is the path of the my file which type is MainMenu.  myRecentFile is NSSarray which stores different paths corresponding to the tableview row.

Comment: What does the `NSLog ()` call print? Is anything written to the console? The `withApplication:` parameter should be the name of an application, not the name of a nib file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a list of Nibs that you want to load, using an "open" button. You probably want to use NSBundle's [loadNibNamed:owner:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSBundle_AppKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSBundle/loadNibNamed%3aowner%3a) class method for the nibs, like the following:

```
- (IBAction)open:(id)sender {
    NSInteger selectedRow = [tableview selectedRow];
    NSString * nibName = [arrayOfNibs objectAtIndex:selectedRow];
    [NSBundle loadNibNamed:nibName owner:NSApp]; 
}
```

However, `nibName` shouldn't contain any path information, which it seems your table provides. You may want to read Apple's [Loading Nibs Programmatically](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i-CH4-SW24) to find the best solution to the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: nonono, you misunderstand me, myrecentfile is NSSArray, which stores the different paths corresponding the tableview row. what i wanna do is to open it. when i select one row, I will get the row number and also get the paths corresponding to that row. what i wanna do is try to open that path using some particular way..